# Ruby: Convert dollar (String) to cents (Integer)

Tags: ruby, currency

How do I convert a string with a dollar amount such as `"5.32"` or `"100"` to an integer amount in cents such as `532` or `10000`?

I have a solution below:

```
dollar_amount_string = "5.32"
dollar_amount_bigdecimal = BigDecimal.new(dollar_amount_string)
cents_amount_bigdecimal = dollar_amount_bigdecimal * BigDecimal.new(100)
cents_amount_int = cents_amount_bigdecimal.to_i
```

but it seems wonky. I want to be sure because this will be an input to the PayPal API.

I've also tried the money gem, but it wasn't able to take strings as inputs.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your solution. `require 'bigdecimal'; (100*BigDecimal.new("5.32")).to_i #=> 532; (100*BigDecimal.new("12")).to_i #=> 1200`. Note that `100*BigDecimal.new("5.32")` is a big decimal, just as `2 * 3.1 #=> 6.2` is a `Float`.

Comment: Money should not be handled with floats - best to use a function that converts to integers https://stackoverflow.com/a/54355052/1536309

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [String#to_r](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_r) ("to rational") to avoid round-off error.

```
def dollars_to_cents(dollars)
  (100 * dollars.to_r).to_i
end

dollars_to_cents("12")
  #=> 1200 
dollars_to_cents("10.25")
  #=> 1025 
dollars_to_cents("-10.25")
  #=> -1025 
dollars_to_cents("-0")
  #=> 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d, c = dollar_amount_string.split(".")
d.to_i * 100 + c.to_i # => 532
```

Comment: That's cool. Readers; `"d, c = "100".split(".") #=> ["100"] `, so `d #=> "100"`, `c #=> nil`. `"100".to_i * 100 + nil.to_i #=> 10000 + 0 #=> 10000`.

Comment: Not so fast. `10.0020` will show up as 1020. You have to respect those decimal places. Fractional cents do show up as the result of some calculations.

Comment: @tadman I haven't seen a price like that. Is that a valid price?

Comment: `$1.02` plus 5% tax, for example.

Comment: @tadman Is that an example of `string with a dollar amount such as "5.32" or "100"`?

Comment: You're *probably* okay with this solution. I'm just saying it is not general purpose and has limitations, so a warning is in order. Cary's `.to_r` approach works more reliably.

Comment: Thank you Cary. Coincidentally, in a day or two, I am going to publicize a Ruby gem that I have been working on for some time.

Comment: Where will we see it?

Answer (score 1):

I started with the [original accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36951467/1536309), but had to make some important fixes along the way:

```
def dollars_to_cents(string=nil)
  # remove all the signs and formatting
  nums = string.to_s.strip.delete("$ CAD ,")
  # add CENTS if they do not exit
  nums = nums + ".00" unless nums.include?(".")
  return (100 * nums.strip.to_r).to_i
end
```

#### So far works with these inputs:

- `CAD 1,215.92`
- `CAD 1230.00`
- `$11123.23`
- `$123`
- `43234.87`
- `43,234.87`